# How to keep integrity of windows firewall while packet sniffing?

Tags: c++, packet-sniffers, windows-firewall

I'm working on a packet sniffer(C++ & winsock) that will detect intrusions. The issue I'm having is when windows firewall is enabled the packet sniffer doesn't pick up the packets I'm searching for.

My sniffer works perfect when the firewall is disabled, so my question is:
How can I keep the integrity of my windows firewall while keeping the functionality of my sniffer? Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Also how is this happening. If HTTP is open and I do something like ?id='ATTACK STRING' how is my sniffer not picking that packet up? Is the firewall blocking my sniffer, or is it filtering the traffic from HTTP?

I've tried adding my sniffer to firewall exemptions as well and no luck.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to answer your questions without knowing how you implemented your packet sniffer.

Comment: what would you like to know? I'm just using winsock & c++

Comment: The only way to sniff packets with Winsock is to use RAW sockets, which requires admin rights. Also, Winsock is an application-level API. For proper sniffing, you should be using a network-layer API instead. Have a look at [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org), for instance. That is what [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) uses on Windows platforms.

Comment: Admin rights isn't an issue, I'm running my sniffer as Administrator.I'm pretty sure winpcap will have the same firewall issues. No?

Comment: WinPcap operates at the networking layer where your app does not. Whether or not it is subject to a firewall depends on where the firewall is located. But if you look at the feature list of WinPCap, one of its (many) intended purposes is for intrusion detection systems.